# Rename elements of a list from a vector file [R]

Tags: r, csv, lapply

I have here a list:

```
    df.list <- list(structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:33:13", "2023-02-14 14:33:13"
), lat = c(50.085588, 50.0855878333333), lon = c(4.55540016666667, 
4.5554), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:29:21", "2023-02-14 13:29:22"
    ), lat = c(50.0855996666667, 50.0855998333333), lon = c(4.55512916666667, 
    4.555129), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:39:30", "2023-02-14 13:39:31"
    ), lat = c(50.0856193333333, 50.0856195), lon = c(4.55519116666667, 
    4.5551915), alt = c(196.1, 196.1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:38:54", "2023-02-14 13:38:55"
    ), lat = c(50.0856118333333, 50.0856118333333), lon = c(4.555187, 
    4.55518716666667), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:14:30", "2023-02-14 14:14:31"
    ), lat = c(50.0856361666667, 50.0856361666667), lon = c(4.55524916666667, 
    4.55524966666667), alt = c(195.6, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:36:21", "2023-02-14 14:36:21"
    ), lat = c(50.0855886666667, 50.0855886666667), lon = c(4.55543483333333, 
    4.55543466666667), alt = c(196.9, 196.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:28:20", "2023-02-14 13:28:21"
    ), lat = c(50.0856001666667, 50.0856003333333), lon = c(4.55512016666667, 
    4.55511983333333), alt = c(196.2, 196.2)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:34:59", "2023-02-14 13:35:00"
    ), lat = c(50.085614, 50.0856141666667), lon = c(4.555184, 
    4.55518416666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:24:10", "2023-02-14 14:24:11"
    ), lat = c(50.0856, 50.0856001666667), lon = c(4.55531633333333, 
    4.55531583333333), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:26:25", "2023-02-14 13:26:26"
    ), lat = c(50.0855585, 50.0855583333333), lon = c(4.55509816666667, 
    4.55509816666667), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:32:33", "2023-02-14 13:32:34"
    ), lat = c(50.0856156666667, 50.0856155), lon = c(4.55516366666667, 
    4.55516366666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:30:04", "2023-02-14 13:30:05"
    ), lat = c(50.0855856666667, 50.0855855), lon = c(4.55513816666667, 
    4.55513866666667), alt = c(196.3, 196.3)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:30:52", "2023-02-14 13:30:53"
    ), lat = c(50.0856061666667, 50.0856061666667), lon = c(4.55516116666667, 
    4.555161), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:24:23", "2023-02-14 13:24:24"
    ), lat = c(50.0855631666667, 50.0855631666667), lon = c(4.55508666666667, 
    4.55508683333333), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:29:07", "2023-02-14 14:29:07"
    ), lat = c(50.0855993333333, 50.0855993333333), lon = c(4.5553505, 
    4.55535083333333), alt = c(194.4, 194.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:34:33", "2023-02-14 14:34:33"
    ), lat = c(50.085565, 50.085565), lon = c(4.55539216666667, 
    4.55539216666667), alt = c(196.1, 196.1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:31:46", "2023-02-14 13:31:47"
    ), lat = c(50.0855913333333, 50.0855913333333), lon = c(4.55516316666667, 
    4.55516316666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:38:58", "2023-02-14 14:38:58"
    ), lat = c(50.0855555, 50.0855555), lon = c(4.55541816666667, 
    4.55541833333333), alt = c(196.1, 196.1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:17:03", "2023-02-14 14:17:03"
    ), lat = c(50.0856198333333, 50.0856196666667), lon = c(4.55523316666667, 
    4.55523316666667), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:33:52", "2023-02-14 13:33:53"
    ), lat = c(50.0855915, 50.0855913333333), lon = c(4.55516533333333, 
    4.55516566666667), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:20:15", "2023-02-14 14:20:16"
    ), lat = c(50.0856486666667, 50.0856485), lon = c(4.55524616666667, 
    4.555246), alt = c(196.1, 196.1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:25:46", "2023-02-14 13:25:47"
    ), lat = c(50.085564, 50.0855641666667), lon = c(4.555103, 
    4.55510283333333), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:15:11", "2023-02-14 14:15:11"
    ), lat = c(50.0856263333333, 50.0856263333333), lon = c(4.55524366666667, 
    4.555244), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:37:21", "2023-02-14 15:37:22"
    ), lat = c(50.0855968333333, 50.0855968333333), lon = c(4.55584216666667, 
    4.55584216666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:21:50", "2023-02-14 13:21:51"
    ), lat = c(50.0855355, 50.0855353333333), lon = c(4.55500733333333, 
    4.55500716666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:22:14", "2023-02-14 14:22:14"
    ), lat = c(50.0856335, 50.0856335), lon = c(4.55530833333333, 
    4.55530833333333), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:17:40", "2023-02-14 14:17:40"
    ), lat = c(50.0856283333333, 50.0856283333333), lon = c(4.55523816666667, 
    4.5552385), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:11:32", "2023-02-14 14:11:32"
    ), lat = c(50.0856538333333, 50.0856531666667), lon = c(4.55523933333333, 
    4.55523966666667), alt = c(194.7, 194.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:15:59", "2023-02-14 14:16:00"
    ), lat = c(50.085632, 50.085632), lon = c(4.5552615, 4.55526183333333
    ), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:59:04", "2023-02-14 14:59:04"
    ), lat = c(50.0855613333333, 50.0855613333333), lon = c(4.5554735, 
    4.55547283333333), alt = c(197, 197)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:13:12", "2023-02-14 14:13:13"
    ), lat = c(50.0856505, 50.0856506666667), lon = c(4.55523633333333, 
    4.55523633333333), alt = c(194.6, 194.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:32:37", "2023-02-14 14:32:37"
    ), lat = c(50.085606, 50.0856061666667), lon = c(4.55541633333333, 
    4.55541633333333), alt = c(196.3, 196.3)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:25:28", "2023-02-14 14:25:28"
    ), lat = c(50.085589, 50.085589), lon = c(4.55532783333333, 
    4.55532783333333), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:10:13", "2023-02-14 14:10:13"
    ), lat = c(50.0856455, 50.0856455), lon = c(4.55524866666667, 
    4.55524866666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:11:51", "2023-02-14 14:11:51"
    ), lat = c(50.0856356666667, 50.0856358333333), lon = c(4.55522716666667, 
    4.55522716666667), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:00:10", "2023-02-14 13:00:11"
    ), lat = c(50.085519, 50.085519), lon = c(4.55486433333333, 
    4.55486433333333), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:15:03", "2023-02-14 13:15:04"
    ), lat = c(50.085515, 50.085515), lon = c(4.5548905, 4.5548905
    ), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:12:39", "2023-02-14 13:12:40"
    ), lat = c(50.0855135, 50.0855135), lon = c(4.5548845, 4.55488433333333
    ), alt = c(195.8, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:09:51", "2023-02-14 13:09:52"
    ), lat = c(50.0855061666667, 50.085506), lon = c(4.554888, 
    4.55488816666667), alt = c(195.1, 195)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:02:16", "2023-02-14 13:02:17"
    ), lat = c(50.0855231666667, 50.0855231666667), lon = c(4.55488, 
    4.55487983333333), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:26:28", "2023-02-14 14:26:28"
    ), lat = c(50.085593, 50.0855931666667), lon = c(4.55534183333333, 
    4.55534183333333), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:08:12", "2023-02-14 13:08:13"
    ), lat = c(50.0855063333333, 50.0855063333333), lon = c(4.5548845, 
    4.5548845), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:01:28", "2023-02-14 13:01:29"
    ), lat = c(50.0855268333333, 50.0855268333333), lon = c(4.55487533333333, 
    4.55487583333333), alt = c(195.9, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:30:59", "2023-02-14 14:31:00"
    ), lat = c(50.0855911666667, 50.0855911666667), lon = c(4.55538766666667, 
    4.55538733333333), alt = c(196.6, 196.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:20:18", "2023-02-14 13:20:19"
    ), lat = c(50.0855385, 50.0855386666667), lon = c(4.5549915, 
    4.55499116666667), alt = c(196.1, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:07:05", "2023-02-14 13:07:06"
    ), lat = c(50.0855238333333, 50.085524), lon = c(4.55489133333333, 
    4.55489116666667), alt = c(197, 197)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 12:46:35", "2023-02-14 12:46:36"
    ), lat = c(50.08553, 50.0855301666667), lon = c(4.55487016666667, 
    4.55487016666667), alt = c(196.8, 196.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:13:52", "2023-02-14 13:13:53"
    ), lat = c(50.0855223333333, 50.0855225), lon = c(4.55489, 
    4.55489016666667), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:35:42", "2023-02-14 13:35:43"
    ), lat = c(50.085597, 50.085597), lon = c(4.55519583333333, 
    4.55519583333333), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:36:59", "2023-02-14 14:37:00"
    ), lat = c(50.0855678333333, 50.0855676666667), lon = c(4.5554255, 
    4.55542533333333), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:37:19", "2023-02-14 13:37:20"
    ), lat = c(50.0856065, 50.0856065), lon = c(4.55519516666667, 
    4.55519533333333), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:57:13", "2023-02-14 14:57:13"
    ), lat = c(50.0855648333333, 50.0855668333333), lon = c(4.55544983333333, 
    4.5554505), alt = c(194.8, 194.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:21:27", "2023-02-14 14:21:27"
    ), lat = c(50.0856253333333, 50.0856261666667), lon = c(4.55531183333333, 
    4.55531333333333), alt = c(195, 195)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:24:47", "2023-02-14 14:24:47"
    ), lat = c(50.085599, 50.085599), lon = c(4.555322, 4.55532216666667
    ), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:32:02", "2023-02-14 14:32:02"
    ), lat = c(50.0856021666667, 50.0856021666667), lon = c(4.5553805, 
    4.5553805), alt = c(195.6, 195.5)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:38:11", "2023-02-14 13:38:12"
    ), lat = c(50.0856053333333, 50.0856053333333), lon = c(4.5551895, 
    4.55518966666667), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:39:38", "2023-02-14 14:39:39"
    ), lat = c(50.0855733333333, 50.0855731666667), lon = c(4.55541783333333, 
    4.55541783333333), alt = c(196.6, 196.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 13:36:34", "2023-02-14 13:36:35"
    ), lat = c(50.0856043333333, 50.0856043333333), lon = c(4.555195, 
    4.555195), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:23:15", "2023-02-14 14:23:15"
    ), lat = c(50.0855998333333, 50.0855998333333), lon = c(4.55529116666667, 
    4.55529116666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:27:51", "2023-02-14 14:27:51"
    ), lat = c(50.0856001666667, 50.0856), lon = c(4.5553565, 
    4.5553565), alt = c(196.7, 196.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:28:31", "2023-02-14 14:28:32"
    ), lat = c(50.0855761666667, 50.0855761666667), lon = c(4.55535483333333, 
    4.55535483333333), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:51:31", "2023-02-14 14:51:31"
    ), lat = c(50.085597, 50.0855971666667), lon = c(4.555469, 
    4.55546916666667), alt = c(197.5, 197.5)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:14:10", "2023-02-14 15:14:10"
    ), lat = c(50.085603, 50.085601), lon = c(4.5555135, 4.55551683333333
    ), alt = c(195.1, 195.1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:38:16", "2023-02-14 14:38:16"
    ), lat = c(50.085572, 50.0855718333333), lon = c(4.5554355, 
    4.5554355), alt = c(196.1, 196.2)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:18:52", "2023-02-14 15:18:52"
    ), lat = c(50.0856136666667, 50.0856136666667), lon = c(4.5556125, 
    4.55561266666667), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:26:24", "2023-02-14 15:26:24"
    ), lat = c(50.0856231666667, 50.0856235), lon = c(4.5556855, 
    4.555686), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:32:37", "2023-02-14 15:32:37"
    ), lat = c(50.0855908333333, 50.085591), lon = c(4.555776, 
    4.555776), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:29:45", "2023-02-14 15:29:45"
    ), lat = c(50.0855873333333, 50.0855871666667), lon = c(4.55573133333333, 
    4.5557305), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:27:14", "2023-02-14 15:27:15"
    ), lat = c(50.0856126666667, 50.0856123333333), lon = c(4.55569433333333, 
    4.55569466666667), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:06:59", "2023-02-14 15:06:59"
    ), lat = c(50.0855725, 50.085573), lon = c(4.55551, 4.55551
    ), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:47:27", "2023-02-14 15:47:28"
    ), lat = c(50.0856143333333, 50.085615), lon = c(4.55612283333333, 
    4.55612266666667), alt = c(197, 197.2)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:56:02", "2023-02-14 14:56:02"
    ), lat = c(50.0855743333333, 50.0855738333333), lon = c(4.55546416666667, 
    4.55546416666667), alt = c(196.8, 196.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:02:53", "2023-02-14 15:02:54"
    ), lat = c(50.08558, 50.0855801666667), lon = c(4.55546933333333, 
    4.55546916666667), alt = c(196.4, 196.4)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:31:27", "2023-02-14 15:31:28"
    ), lat = c(50.0856178333333, 50.085618), lon = c(4.55578316666667, 
    4.55578316666667), alt = c(196.6, 196.5)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:08:36", "2023-02-14 16:08:36"
    ), lat = c(50.0856126666667, 50.0856121666667), lon = c(4.55632333333333, 
    4.556323), alt = c(196.9, 196.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:14:05", "2023-02-14 16:14:06"
    ), lat = c(50.0856433333333, 50.0856431666667), lon = c(4.55659083333333, 
    4.55659083333333), alt = c(197.2, 197.2)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:07:59", "2023-02-14 15:07:59"
    ), lat = c(50.0855476666667, 50.0855476666667), lon = c(4.55550666666667, 
    4.55550683333333), alt = c(195.6, 195.5)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:01:22", "2023-02-14 15:01:23"
    ), lat = c(50.0855551666667, 50.0855553333333), lon = c(4.55547383333333, 
    4.55547366666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:22:51", "2023-02-14 16:22:51"
    ), lat = c(50.0858058333333, 50.085806), lon = c(4.55701266666667, 
    4.557013), alt = c(197, 196.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:24:31", "2023-02-14 15:24:31"
    ), lat = c(50.0856235, 50.0856235), lon = c(4.5556625, 4.5556625
    ), alt = c(195.9, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:56:58", "2023-02-14 14:56:58"
    ), lat = c(50.0855568333333, 50.0855568333333), lon = c(4.55544083333333, 
    4.55544066666667), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:27:12", "2023-02-14 16:27:13"
    ), lat = c(50.0858683333333, 50.0858683333333), lon = c(4.55712366666667, 
    4.55712283333333), alt = c(196.9, 196.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:08:46", "2023-02-14 15:08:47"
    ), lat = c(50.0855598333333, 50.08556), lon = c(4.55551833333333, 
    4.55551833333333), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:23:59", "2023-02-14 16:23:59"
    ), lat = c(50.0858056666667, 50.0858058333333), lon = c(4.55700616666667, 
    4.55700616666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:00:58", "2023-02-14 15:00:59"
    ), lat = c(50.0855675, 50.0855676666667), lon = c(4.5554855, 
    4.55548566666667), alt = c(196.5, 196.5)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:41:33", "2023-02-14 15:41:33"
    ), lat = c(50.0856088333333, 50.0856093333333), lon = c(4.55588816666667, 
    4.55588816666667), alt = c(194.8, 194.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:49:17", "2023-02-14 15:49:17"
    ), lat = c(50.0856085, 50.0856086666667), lon = c(4.55617033333333, 
    4.55617083333333), alt = c(197, 197)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:12:49", "2023-02-14 15:12:49"
    ), lat = c(50.0855995, 50.0855993333333), lon = c(4.55548366666667, 
    4.55548383333333), alt = c(195.5, 195.5)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:00:04", "2023-02-14 15:00:04"
    ), lat = c(50.0855471666667, 50.085547), lon = c(4.55546633333333, 
    4.55546633333333), alt = c(195.9, 195.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:19:51", "2023-02-14 15:19:51"
    ), lat = c(50.0856081666667, 50.085608), lon = c(4.55562966666667, 
    4.5556295), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:52:49", "2023-02-14 14:52:49"
    ), lat = c(50.0855915, 50.0855915), lon = c(4.5554585, 4.55545916666667
    ), alt = c(195, 195.2)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:35:50", "2023-02-14 15:35:50"
    ), lat = c(50.0855946666667, 50.0855946666667), lon = c(4.55583466666667, 
    4.55583466666667), alt = c(196.1, 196.1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:42:33", "2023-02-14 15:42:33"
    ), lat = c(50.0856031666667, 50.0856033333333), lon = c(4.55590166666667, 
    4.55590166666667), alt = c(195.7, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:11:28", "2023-02-14 15:11:28"
    ), lat = c(50.0855835, 50.0855833333333), lon = c(4.55551433333333, 
    4.55551416666667), alt = c(196.5, 196.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:16:57", "2023-02-14 15:16:57"
    ), lat = c(50.0856133333333, 50.0856135), lon = c(4.55559883333333, 
    4.55559833333333), alt = c(196.2, 196.2)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:39:07", "2023-02-14 15:39:07"
    ), lat = c(50.0856143333333, 50.085614), lon = c(4.555848, 
    4.55584816666667), alt = c(195.7, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 14:54:20", "2023-02-14 14:54:21"
    ), lat = c(50.085583, 50.085583), lon = c(4.555483, 4.555483
    ), alt = c(196.1, 196.1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:51:51", "2023-02-14 15:51:51"
    ), lat = c(50.0855886666667, 50.0855881666667), lon = c(4.55624983333333, 
    4.55625066666667), alt = c(196.3, 196.3)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:04:17", "2023-02-14 15:04:18"
    ), lat = c(50.0855578333333, 50.0855578333333), lon = c(4.55549733333333, 
    4.55549766666667), alt = c(195.8, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:35:09", "2023-02-14 15:35:09"
    ), lat = c(50.0855715, 50.0855715), lon = c(4.5558175, 4.5558175
    ), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:40:20", "2023-02-14 15:40:21"
    ), lat = c(50.0856128333333, 50.0856131666667), lon = c(4.55587233333333, 
    4.5558725), alt = c(194.4, 194.4)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:38:24", "2023-02-14 15:38:24"
    ), lat = c(50.0856028333333, 50.0856028333333), lon = c(4.5558445, 
    4.55584466666667), alt = c(195.6, 195.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:25:23", "2023-02-14 16:25:24"
    ), lat = c(50.0858448333333, 50.0858445), lon = c(4.55710433333333, 
    4.55710416666667), alt = c(196.5, 196.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:34:09", "2023-02-14 15:34:09"
    ), lat = c(50.0855921666667, 50.0855921666667), lon = c(4.55580083333333, 
    4.55580083333333), alt = c(195.9, 195.8)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:03:49", "2023-02-14 15:03:49"
    ), lat = c(50.0855466666667, 50.0855466666667), lon = c(4.55548433333333, 
    4.55548383333333), alt = c(196, 196)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 15:28:39", "2023-02-14 15:28:39"
    ), lat = c(50.0856093333333, 50.08561), lon = c(4.555721, 
    4.5557215), alt = c(195.6, 195.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:40:30", "2023-02-14 16:40:30"
    ), lat = c(50.0847675, 50.0847673333333), lon = c(4.5522415, 
    4.5522415), alt = c(202.7, 202.7)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 12:36:46", "2023-02-14 12:36:47"
    ), lat = c(50.0855291666667, 50.0855291666667), lon = c(4.55525866666667, 
    4.55525866666667), alt = c(197.4, 197.4)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 12:38:04", "2023-02-14 12:38:05"
    ), lat = c(50.085533, 50.0855333333333), lon = c(4.55529516666667, 
    4.55529566666667), alt = c(196.8, 196.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 12:31:58", "2023-02-14 12:31:59"
    ), lat = c(50.0853416666667, 50.0853415), lon = c(4.55401133333333, 
    4.554011), alt = c(197.9, 197.9)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 12:33:13", "2023-02-14 12:33:14"
    ), lat = c(50.0853436666667, 50.0853445), lon = c(4.55403066666667, 
    4.55403083333333), alt = c(197.2, 197.4)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 12:29:48", "2023-02-14 12:29:49"
    ), lat = c(50.0852323333333, 50.0852321666667), lon = c(4.55357316666667, 
    4.55357366666667), alt = c(198.6, 198.6)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(time = c("2023-02-14 16:45:13", "2023-02-14 16:45:13"
    ), lat = c(50.085568, 50.0855681666667), lon = c(4.55523516666667, 
    4.555235), alt = c(198.4, 198.3)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"))
```

Imported from different .csv files with that code:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern='*.csv', full.names=TRUE)
df.list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)

dput(filenames)
c("./12112.csv", "./12201.csv", "./12202.csv", "./12203.csv", 
"./12208.csv", "./12209.csv", "./12210.csv", "./12215.csv", "./12216.csv", 
"./12220.csv", "./12223.csv", "./12225.csv", "./12226.csv", "./12230.csv", 
"./12232.csv", "./12234.csv", "./12246.csv", "./12248.csv", "./12249.csv", 
"./12251.csv", "./12253.csv", "./12261.csv", "./12262.csv", "./12267.csv", 
"./12268.csv", "./12269.csv", "./12271.csv", "./12276.csv", "./12277.csv", 
"./12279.csv", "./12282.csv", "./12283.csv", "./12290.csv", "./12294.csv", 
"./12299.csv", "./13102.csv", "./13104.csv", "./13106.csv", "./13107.csv", 
"./13108.csv", "./13114.csv", "./13117.csv", "./13119.csv", "./13121.csv", 
"./13124.csv", "./13125.csv", "./13126.csv", "./13130.csv", "./13137.csv", 
"./13140.csv", "./13142.csv", "./13147.csv", "./13148.csv", "./13150.csv", 
"./13151.csv", "./13152.csv", "./13154.csv", "./13157.csv", "./13158.csv", 
"./13162.csv", "./13163.csv", "./13180.csv", "./13193.csv", "./13197.csv", 
"./13200.csv", "./2206.csv", "./2207.csv", "./2211.csv", "./2213.csv", 
"./2219.csv", "./2229.csv", "./2235.csv", "./2236.csv", "./2239.csv", 
"./2244.csv", "./2257.csv", "./2260.csv", "./2264.csv", "./2265.csv", 
"./2266.csv", "./2274.csv", "./2286.csv", "./2288.csv", "./2289.csv", 
"./2291.csv", "./2298.csv", "./3103.csv", "./3135.csv", "./3136.csv", 
"./3138.csv", "./3144.csv", "./3149.csv", "./3159.csv", "./3161.csv", 
"./3165.csv", "./3173.csv", "./3176.csv", "./3177.csv", "./3178.csv", 
"./3181.csv", "./3183.csv", "./3184.csv", "./3185.csv", "./3188.csv", 
"./3191.csv", "./3199.csv", "./BorneSNCB.csv", "./Panneau1droit.csv", 
"./Panneau1gauche.csv", "./Panneau3droite.csv", "./Panneau3gauche.csv", 
"./Piquet0uhab.csv", "./Piquetrisberme.csv")
```

Nevertheless the df.list does not keep the names of the CSV. hese names which are contained in the vector "filenames".

Therefore, I am looking for a way to use the values from "filenames" to name each data.frame of the list "df.list"
(or a way to keep the names during the importation of the .csv files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default action of `lapply` is to keep names (of the original `list.files(.)` vector/list) but it does not supply names if they don't exist. Contrasting with `sapply` that applies names when they do not apply (using its default `USE.NAMES=TRUE`).

Three ways around this:

1. Apply the names manually post-read:

   ```r
   names(df.list) <- filenames
   ```

   This is easiest when you've already read in all the data and don't want to take the time to read it all again.
2. Assign names using `setNames`, as in

   ```r
   lapply(setNames(nm=filenames), read.csv)
   ```

   This is my preferred when starting from scratch.
3. Use `sapply`, adding `simplify=FALSE`:

   ```r
   sapply(filenames, read.csv, simplify=FALSE)
   ```